# group scheme of prime order p is killed by p

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In the article "Group Schemes of Prime Order" by Tate and Oort (see [here](http://homepages.uni-regensburg.de/~nan25776/tate_oort_group_schemes_of_prime_order.pdf)) it is proved that a group scheme of prime order $p$ over the base $S$ is killed by $p$ (Theorem 1). The authors state that it clearly suffices to consider the case $S = $ Spec$(R)$, where $R$ is a local ring with algebraically closed residue class field. I don't quite understand this reduction and would be thankful if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: I am reading your link (not so keenly, though): the fact that a group scheme $G$ of order $p$ is killed by $p$ is a consequence of the Deligne's Theorem (at the beginning of page 4) whose proof doesn't reduce to the case of Spec$(R)$. But  Theroem 1 also claim the commutativity of $G$: if I am right this property should be local on the base (you can decompose the base in affine opens and work on them). Does it make sense for you?

Comment: yes, commutativity is the key in the proof and it can indeed be checked, when $S = Spec (R)$ is assumed affine. What I don't get is, why it is sufficient that $R$ is taken to be local with algebraically closed residue class field.

Comment: Ok, I see. Your question is about the "local with algebraically closed residue class field"..I am sorry but I don't think to get it now. Hope someone else could help you. Cheers!